# How to set ScrollView height with different height constrains and self-sizing labels?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm building a scrollView page and it has height constraint ( for example 1300 )
But there is labels need to expand each other ( line height = 0 )

[image]

How can i manage scrollView heightConstraint efficient way ?

Comment: you have 3 textField and 1 label right?

3 textField have fixed height?

Comment: Yes. But maybe in future i can add some textfield under the label

Comment: ok so just add height of each textField and remove height of scroll view.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make scrollView Self sizing you have to set this constraints which pins it to borders of view and doesn't sets certain height for it but instead it uses height of a content inside of scrollView.

```
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pin a stack view to the scroll view (or to the layout margins of the scroll view) which will allow the resizing according to the content:

```swift
let stackView = UIStackView()
scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
    stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor)
])
```

Just make sure to provide the `intrinsicContentSize` for the arranged subviews or at least provide the height for each if you're using `.fill`, `equalSpacing`, or `equalCentering` for the distribution.